# Java Help(FileStream)

Tags: java, stream, runtime.exec

I want to execute notepad(C:\a.txt) after typing another char.

This code open a.txt with notepad but when i was write "Java" , i want to show my console Java. after when i was write " then Java" i want to show my console Java then Java".

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("notepad.exe C:\\a.txt");
InputStreamReader read = new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream());
while(read.read() != -1){
System.out.println(read.read());
}
```

Comment: You need to keep track of already printed line, may be add it "arrayList".

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to read what's going on in `Notepad` this way.

`getInputStream()`/`getOutputStream` allow you to *write to* and *read from* the [standard input and output](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams) of a process, but these streams typically have nothing to do with the user interface of a desktop application. Notepad isn't going to echo things that happen in it's user interface to these streams.

You can monitor the file system for changes to *a.txt* but this assumes that you're *saving* the file after each change in Notepad.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to detect changes while file is opened you can use https://blogs.oracle.com/thejavatutorials/entry/watching_a_directory_for_changes#register and then re-read the file with the code you provided